# Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом

Tags: android

Единственное место кода, где происходит работа с reader'ом и InputStream'ом. Почему выводится ошибка, я ведь все, что открывал для чтения, везде закрыл. Причем в другом проекте точно такой же участок кода работает без ошибок

```
  class TestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


        String search = wordEnglish.getText().toString();


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wordEnglish",search));

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://siteforproject.000webhostapp.com/get_products_details.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity enity = response.getEntity();
            is = enity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        }


        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 100);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            reader.close();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection" + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }

        try {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
             wordEnglishText = (json_data.getString("wordEnglish"));
            defenitionEnglishText = (json_data.getString("defenitionEnglish"));
            wordRussianText = (json_data.getString("wordRussian"));
            defenitionRussianText = (json_data.getString("defenitionRussian"));
            wordChinaText = (json_data.getString("wordChina"));
            defenitionChinaText = (json_data.getString("defenitionChina"));
            wordJapanText = (json_data.getString("wordJapan"));
            defenition_JapanText = (json_data.getString("defenition_Japan"));
            Log.e("pass 3", wordEnglishText);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        System.out.println(values[0]);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же учтите, что доступ к файлам у вас происходит в асинхронном режиме, а это значит то что вы как бы закрыли, не обязательно закрыто на самом деле. Вам нужно добавить проверку чтобы быть уверенным в том что у вас этот файл закрыт на самом деле и готов к работе.

```
if(reader.ready()){
  //делаете ваши дела
}
```

Но так у вас доступ к файлу происходит уже в самой задачи, то вам нужно вынести проверку за пределы задачи или как вариант можно сделать несколько попыток с ожиданием, например:

```
int counterTry = 0;
if(reader.ready()){
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     sb.append(line + "\n");
  }
} else {
  if(counterTry == 5){
    wait(1000);
    counterTry++; 
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: в последнем else оставшийся код вложить нужно, верно?

Comment: @toofack, не совсем, это только дополнение к циклу while, но вы разработчик, вам виднее что с этим делать.